# "have pain in something" or "have a pain in something"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Tell me please which one of the folowing sentences is correct.

> Because I have pain in my arm, I cannot pull it.
>
> Because I have **a** pain in my arm, I cannot pull it.

Comment: (+1) I am a learner, I use the variant with *a* usually, since it's pointing out a very specific instant of pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct in colloquial English.

One uses `pain` as a countable noun, e.g. `a pain in my arm and a pain in my leg`, the other as uncountable, which, like water, does not require an article. It's a very small difference, and would go unnoticed in connected speech.

That said, a doctor would be more likely to use the uncountable form, e.g. `Do you have pain when walking?`